# Bootstrap 4.3.1 btn-facebook wont show

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-4

I am trying to use Bootstrap 4.3.1 on my Asp.net core mvc project but it seems like it doesn't work any ideas?

```html
        <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>Hello, world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello, w!!</h1>
        <button class="btn btn-facebook"> TEST </button>

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

this is what I see when I run the project:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use https://github.com/lipis/bootstrap-social?

Comment: its not default have in bootstrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

class `.btn-facebook` is not included in bootstrap css, maybe you need to include an external library like [bootstrap-social](https://lipis.github.io/bootstrap-social/)

Comment: I added it now, still looks funky it's probably the way I'm using it or something..ill figure it out

Comment: add the classes: btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook